# Why I cannot access my object using useLocation() react-router-dom v6

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-router-dom

**Listitem component:**

```
const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const getMovie = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get("/movies/find/" + item,
          {
            headers: {
              token: "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYzYTQxNzViOTM1ZWYxODY1YmRjMDRmNCIsImlzQWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTY3MjIzODY2NywiZXhwIjoxNjcyNjcwNjY3fQ.R99XRjYNMSy0jF7glDx9WVsDLYoVAeOcjTB8kEdf4yQ",
            }
          })
        setMovie(res.data)

      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
    getMovie();
  }, [item])

//Cannot access movie in my Watch component using rrdv6 Link
  console.log(movie);
  return (
    <Link to={{ pathname: '/watch', state: { movie } }}>
```

**Watch component:**

```
import './watch.scss'
import ArrowBackIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowBack';
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Watch() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const movie = location.state.movie;
  console.log(movie);
  return (
    <div className="watch">
      <Link to="/">
        <div className="back">
          <ArrowBackIcon />
          Home
        </div>
      </Link>
      <video className="video" autoPlay progress controls src={movie.video} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I try to `console.log` the `movie` in `Watch` component its shows

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'movie')

Please let me know if you want some additional information about the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70214766/i-can-not-get-the-state-from-react-router-link-component-using-uselocation-so-h), in `react-router-dom` v6 the state property is outside `to`. Your `Link` should be like this

```
<Link to='/watch' state={ movie }>
```

Comment: Probably better to flag posts as duplicates than to answer linking to the duplicates.

Comment: Missed that, I will keep that in mind next time.